# Error handling in Angular with injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem trying to inject $ http to the factory. I miss the following error in Angular **1.6**:

```
Circular dependency found: $rootScope <- $http <- $exceptionHandler <- $rootScope <- $route
```

And this was what I was doing so far:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    // controller
  })
  .factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$http', function($log, $http) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
      $log.warn(exception, cause);
      // I show only this and it already throws error
      console.log($http);
    }
  }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work around the circular dependency, try the following.

Instead of injecting `$http` directly into the interceptor try injecting the `$injector` and use that directly to get `$http`.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$injector', function($log, $injector) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
        $log.warn(exception, cause);
        // I show only this and it already throws error
        console.log($http);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: @Kleith If the error persists, more information is required. Bulkan's solution above cannot cause a circular dependency error, based on what we know so far.

Comment: It's just the same error `Circular dependency found` that i describe in the question.

Comment: I miss the `[]`, my bad. It works fine but when i tried something else this crash.